# Wordpress - get post with closest zip code

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, find, zipcode

How i can get 8 posts with closest zip code?

For example i my post have code 123-456, and i want get 8 posts with closest zip codes.

I try use this code:

```
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => array('form'),
            'meta_key' => 'zip_code',
            'meta_value' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "zip_code", true),
            'posts_per_page' => 8,
            'fields' => 'ids'
        );
        $related = get_posts($args);

        print_r($related);
    ?>
```

Thanks!